# Breaking the solution to the problem of dealing one pair just to see what happens

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The answer is $\binom {13}1 \binom42 \binom{12}3 \binom 41^3$

I want to break the last term and see what happens. [Struggling with the concept so trying to work with it as much as possible].

$\binom 41^3$ means that $\heartsuit \diamondsuit \spadesuit$ is different from $\diamondsuit \heartsuit \spadesuit$ and $\heartsuit \spadesuit \diamondsuit $

$\binom 42 \binom 41$ means that $\heartsuit \diamondsuit \spadesuit$ is is the same as $\diamondsuit \heartsuit \spadesuit$

$\binom 43$ means that $\heartsuit \diamondsuit \spadesuit$,  $\diamondsuit \heartsuit \spadesuit$, $\heartsuit \spadesuit \diamondsuit $ are all the same.

Basically, in the first case all three suits are ordered, in the second case first two suitss are unordered but the third one is and in the third case none of the suits are ordered.

Does that make sense?

Clarification:

A one pair consists of five cards where two are of the same kind and the other three are of different kinds. How many such hands are possible? The correct answer is $\binom {13}1 \binom42 \binom{12}3 \binom 41^3$. What I am doing is choosing the suits in different ways to see how that affects the correct answer. Want to see if my reasoning holds up.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a description of the original problem?  The brief description you give in the title isn't really sufficient (personally, I don't understand it at all.)

Comment: @ Michael Seifert, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\binom{4}{1}^3$ in the answer *does* mean that suits are ordered, but ordered *with respect to the 3 chosen ranks for the non-pair cards*, not ordered within the hand. The terms $\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{1}$ and $\binom{4}{3}$ would not make sense in this question because there are 3 chosen different ranks not 2 or 1.

I will break down the whole counting process to try and make this clearer:

First I will list, in a table, the ranks of all 4 suits: diamonds $\color{red}{\diamondsuit}$, hearts $\color{red}{\heartsuit}$, spades $\spadesuit$ and clubs $\clubsuit$

\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccccc}
\color{red}{\diamondsuit}&\color{red}{A}&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{3}&\color{red}{4}&\color{red}{5}&\color{red}{6}&\color{red}{7}&\color{red}{8}&\color{red}{9}&\color{red}{10}&\color{red}{J}&\color{red}{Q}&\color{red}{K}\\
\color{red}{\heartsuit}&\color{red}{A}&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{3}&\color{red}{4}&\color{red}{5}&\color{red}{6}&\color{red}{7}&\color{red}{8}&\color{red}{9}&\color{red}{10}&\color{red}{J}&\color{red}{Q}&\color{red}{K}\\
\spadesuit&A&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&J&Q&K\\
\clubsuit&A&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&J&Q&K\\
\end{array}

We have 13 ranks to choose our pair from, there are $\binom{13}{1}$ ways to do this.

So, for example we may choose Jack as our pair rank

\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc|c|cc}
\color{red}{\diamondsuit}&\color{red}{A}&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{3}&\color{red}{4}&\color{red}{5}&\color{red}{6}&\color{red}{7}&\color{red}{8}&\color{red}{9}&\color{red}{10}&\color{red}{J}&\color{red}{Q}&\color{red}{K}\\
\color{red}{\heartsuit}&\color{red}{A}&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{3}&\color{red}{4}&\color{red}{5}&\color{red}{6}&\color{red}{7}&\color{red}{8}&\color{red}{9}&\color{red}{10}&\color{red}{J}&\color{red}{Q}&\color{red}{K}\\
\spadesuit&A&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&J&Q&K\\
\clubsuit&A&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&J&Q&K\\
\end{array}

Then *for each choice of rank* we have 4 suits from which 2 must be chosen for our pair, hence there are $\binom{4}{2}$ choices of suits and $\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}$ total choices of pairs.

For example, we may choose diamonds $\color{red}{\diamondsuit}$ and clubs $\clubsuit$

\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc|c|cc}
\hline\color{red}{\diamondsuit}&\color{red}{A}&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{3}&\color{red}{4}&\color{red}{5}&\color{red}{6}&\color{red}{7}&\color{red}{8}&\color{red}{9}&\color{red}{10}&\color{red}{J}&\color{red}{Q}&\color{red}{K}\\
\hline\color{red}{\heartsuit}&\color{red}{A}&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{3}&\color{red}{4}&\color{red}{5}&\color{red}{6}&\color{red}{7}&\color{red}{8}&\color{red}{9}&\color{red}{10}&\color{red}{J}&\color{red}{Q}&\color{red}{K}\\
\spadesuit&A&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&J&Q&K\\
\hline\clubsuit&A&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&J&Q&K\\
\hline
\end{array}

For *each choice of pair* we must then choose 3 *different ranks* for our non-pair cards, there are 12 ranks remaining from which to choose these 3 ranks. This may be done in $\binom{12}{3}$ ways.

For example: we may choose ranks 3, 6 and 9

\begin{array}{c|cc|c|cc|c|cc|c|cccc}
\color{red}{\diamondsuit}&\color{red}{A}&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{3}&\color{red}{4}&\color{red}{5}&\color{red}{6}&\color{red}{7}&\color{red}{8}&\color{red}{9}&\color{red}{10}&\boxed{\color{red}{J}}&\color{red}{Q}&\color{red}{K}\\
\color{red}{\heartsuit}&\color{red}{A}&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{3}&\color{red}{4}&\color{red}{5}&\color{red}{6}&\color{red}{7}&\color{red}{8}&\color{red}{9}&\color{red}{10}&\color{red}{J}&\color{red}{Q}&\color{red}{K}\\
\spadesuit&A&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&J&Q&K\\
\clubsuit&A&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&\boxed{J}&Q&K\\
\end{array}

In *each* of those 3 chosen ranks we may choose a suit in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways, hence there are $\binom{4}{1}^3$ ways to choose our 3 suits. Thus, *for each chosen pair* we may choose 3 non-pair cards in $\binom{12}{3}\binom{4}{1}^3$ ways.

For example: the 3 could be a spade $\spadesuit$, the 6 a diamond $\color{red}{\diamondsuit}$ and the 9 a club $\clubsuit$ so that one possible hand is

\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccccc}
\color{red}{\diamondsuit}&\color{red}{A}&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{3}&\color{red}{4}&\color{red}{5}&\boxed{\color{red}{6}}&\color{red}{7}&\color{red}{8}&\color{red}{9}&\color{red}{10}&\boxed{\color{red}{J}}&\color{red}{Q}&\color{red}{K}\\
\color{red}{\heartsuit}&\color{red}{A}&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{3}&\color{red}{4}&\color{red}{5}&\color{red}{6}&\color{red}{7}&\color{red}{8}&\color{red}{9}&\color{red}{10}&\color{red}{J}&\color{red}{Q}&\color{red}{K}\\
\spadesuit&A&2&\boxed{3}&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&J&Q&K\\
\clubsuit&A&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&\boxed{9}&10&\boxed{J}&Q&K\\
\end{array}

This *particular* chosen hand is therefore $\{3\spadesuit,\color{red}{6\diamondsuit},9\clubsuit,\color{red}{J\diamondsuit},J\clubsuit\}$ *in any order*.

Hence total count for hands with one pair only

$$\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{3}\binom{4}{1}^3$$

as declared.

Comment: @ N. Shales, Thank you very much for your answer. I hate choosing from among high quality answers, but yours is simply spectacular.

Comment: @gorbachev thank you very much! That means a lot, I'm glad we could help.

Answer (score 1):

Before discussing the last factor, note that the second last factor, $\binom{12}3$ counts the ways to select three from twelve values without repetition.

Now, $\binom{4}{1}^3$ counts ways to pick three suits with repetition.   We need to match these suits to three distinct numbers, so the fact that this counts distinct order arrangements is okay. 
$$\{\heartsuit\heartsuit\heartsuit,\heartsuit\heartsuit\spadesuit,\heartsuit\heartsuit\clubsuit,\heartsuit\heartsuit\diamondsuit, \heartsuit\spadesuit\heartsuit,\ldots,\diamondsuit\diamondsuit\diamondsuit\}$$

---

If we used $\binom{4}3$ we would be selecting three from four suits, without repetition.

$$\{\heartsuit\spadesuit\clubsuit, \heartsuit\spadesuit\diamondsuit, \heartsuit\clubsuit\diamondsuit,\spadesuit\clubsuit\diamondsuit\}$$

To properly match these with the three distinct values, we should multiply by $3!$ ways to arrange three distinct suits.   $\binom {12}3\binom 4 3 3!$ counts the ways to select three cards each of distinct value *and* distinct suit, selected from twelve values and four suits.

---

However, $\binom 42\binom 41$ *attempts to* count ways to select two distinct suit (without repetition) then a third suit which may be a repetition, which miscounts.   Instead we should count: $\binom 4 3 3!+\binom 42\binom 21 3$ ways to select three distinct suits *or* a pair and singleton of suits, to be matched to the three distinct values.